# Can GeforceNOW founders change server locations?

Tags: geforce-now

If I buys the premium membership of GeforceNOW  called "Founding members" in the US , can I change the servers in EU?

Simply a matter of costs.
Reason is the founder members plan costs 24.95 USD / 6 months in the US.
While the European version costs 27,45 € / 6 months.
1€ > 1USD

I am tempted to say YES. Can someone confirm?
[image]

Comment: Do keep in mind that you may have to pay sales taxes, which might bring the overall cost to the same level (or higher). I'd argue that it's not worth the hassle to get the US one if you're in the EU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, GeForce Now founders subscribers can set the server location they want to use.

However, the Auto option assigns you to the nearest server latency-wise, not nearest to your account region.

[image: GeForce Now UI displaying region list]

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know.
So unlike Netflix, the location subscription is independent to the service.

Comment: @RaymondChenon Netflix library is also based on your IP location.